# Where can I find Einstein's paper on relativity first to end?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, specific-reference

Is there online resource where I can find Einstein's all papers on Relativity. I found something [here](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/papers). But no title contains "Relativity". So I think I can't find what I was expecting but maybe I am lazy a bit.

Answer (score 14):

The database you link to has all of Einstein's papers on relativity. It's just a matter of finding them.  Einstein's first two papers from 1905 are:

- Vol 2, doc 23 -- [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/154)
- Vol 2, doc 24 -- [Does the inertia of a body depend upon its energy content](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/186)

The "theory of relativity" didn't exist in 1905, so it didn't make sense to use that term in the title of these papers.  Later writings do use that terminology, e.g., [On the inertia of energy required by the relativity principle](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/252) (1907; vol 3, doc 45).

General relativity used that name from the start, e.g., [Covariance Properties of the Field Equations of the Theory of Gravitation Based on the General Theory of Relativity](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/18) (1914 w/ Grossmann; vol 6, doc 2)

Answer (score 9):

Einstein's first Relativity paper was  "Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper" ("[On the Electrodynamics of Moving  bodies](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/specrel.pdf)"). His second was on the mass energy equivalence.

Both published in 1905, his [Annus mirabilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_Mirabilis_papers#Special_relativity) .

Stephen Hawking reprints some in his book On the Shoulders of Giants.

Einstein rote Relativity: The Special and General Theories for a general audience.

Answer (score 0):

... *all* [Einstein's] papers on Relativity? If you can lay hands on a copy of [Subtle Is the Lord, The Science and the Life of Albert Einstein, by Abraham Pais](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/subtle-is-the-lord-9780192806727?cc=ca&lang=en&) you will find a Bibliography at the end of each chapter. Of course not all chapters are on relativity, but you should be able to pull out references to aid your online searching. Pais was at Princeton with Einstein, and he used to walk with Einstein daily, so he knew him well.

Two folk have already pointed out the really early papers.  *On the electrodynamics of moving bodies* is an absolute delight to read.